# Angular: await for query string parameter but do something else if it doesn't appear

Tags: rxjs, angular-routing

I have tried to formulate a question title the most generic way that applies to my problem.

I have an Angular application where I have to handle authentication over an external requirement: either use a query string parameter `token` that has to be exchanged with the server for a JWT, or try to search for a *JWT refresh token* in the local storage.

It is:

- First test the query string: if there is a queryString parameter `token`, grab the token, delete any JWT in the local storage, exchange the token via API for two JWTs (`id_token` and `refresh_token`)
- Else go for the refresh token: if there is a `refresh_token` in the local storage available, exchange it for a JWT `id_token` via API
- Else, if none of the two are available, the user is unauthenticated and a prompt should be displayed

I used Observables almost the correct way

```
this.queryParamMap$.unsubscribe();
this.queryParamMap$ = this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap
  .subscribe(
    params => {
      let token = params.get('token');
      ........
      if (!!token) {
         doLoginWithToken();
      else if (isJwtRefreshAvailable())
         doLoginWithRefreshToken();
```

There is one problem with this approach: the very first time the application starts up, the query param map is empty, even if I follow a direct browser link `http://localhost:4200?token=AAAAAAAA`. I have to `wait` for the next element which contains the token.

This has two undesirable effects:

1. At the first attempt, being the token `undefined`, the application immediately tries to log in with the refresh token
2. If I filter the `queryParamMap` observable for a token being present, if a token is never present the observable will never emit, thus not activating the subscription.

My problem can be summarized/generalized as follows.

I have an Observable that I know for sure emits `undefined` the very first time, but **either** in no time it could be ready with a proper value, or it won't emit new values after the initial `undefined`.

Else said, while the observable emits `undefined` and my code starts reacting to it (e.g. by testing for token), a new value can be *ready* for emission right away.

How can I solve this in Rxjs? Note that accessing the JWT token from the local storage **is** a synchronous operation, but it's easy to create `Observable.of(localStorage.get(KEY))` which emits immediately if a refresh token is present.

For that, I can't realistically use `race` operator, because the refresh token is always ready and always wins the race.

How can I write asynchronous code that performs like the steps I described earlier?

As the ultimate result of the authentication, an `Observable<UserProfileDto | undefined>` emits the information about the user, which is used to display personalized information.

Comment: it sounds like you could use just `debounceTime()` and if after this debounce the token is still `undefined`, you'll know that the token is not set and won't be present. If you know that all operations you're doing are synchronous you could go even with `debounceTime(0)` that will execute the subscription handler in another JavaScript frame without any delay.

Comment: Good as an answer. I'll try both

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems here:

1. On init you got "undefined" value (its because probably, under the hood, there is some BehaviourSubject emitting its default value). To overcome this, you can add RxJS operator (skip(1)) to skip that first value, but:
2. Problem here is if you do not have query values at all, you will not reach your subscribe function. Its because queryParamMap will emit a value only, if there is a change (and in that case there is not):

You can do it without Angular, to just parse url from:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const params = Object.fromEntries(urlParams.entries());
```

Or using router in Angular:

```
this.router.events
  // Wait for the navigation end event (since component is initialized before angular router navigation is done)
  .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
  .subscribe((event: NavigationStart) => {
    // Take query params snaphot
    const map = this.route.snapshot.queryParams;

  });
```